# Magento Configurable Import CSV

Tags: magento, import

I've got the spreadsheet below...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AjZAunFJlooudFhaQjZFLWZHTGZRc0dwZUMtel9BNmc&output=html

All of the simple products are uploading fine (I've added one as an example). But the configurable is not 'associating' to the products correctly.

When I go into the back-end of Magento after the import and click on the configurable product it asks me which Attributes I would like to assign against the configurable product.

Does anyone know why I cannot associate the configurable product with the simple products? There's obviously an issue with configurable product on the import.

Answer (score 0):

With this function you can Assign/Unassign (merge) list of simple productids to existing configurable product

```
private function _attachProductToConfigurable( $_childProduct, $_configurableProduct ) {
   $loader = Mage::getResourceModel( 'catalog/product_type_configurable' )->load( $_configurableProduct );

   $ids = $_configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds(); 
   $newids = array();
   foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
      $newids[$id] = 1;
   }

   $newids[$_childProduct->getId()] = 1;

   $loader->saveProducts( $_configurableProduct->getId(), array_keys( $newids ) );                
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks - I just want to know why the spreadsheet is not working? This is as Magento suggested it.